# MySQL Performance issue with a cumulative report with 2 columns in the on clause

Tags: mysql

The following SQL runs extremely slow in MySQL.  It takes well over an hour against a table of 250,000 rows (across a 3 year timeline.).

```
select  L.order_date,   
        L.segname, 
        sum(O.product_total) as c_product_total,    
        sum(O.num_orders) as c_num_orders         
from report_PurchasesByOrderDate_Hour_bySegment as L 
join report_PurchasesByOrderDate_Hour_bySegment as O
    on L.order_date >= O.order_date
        and L.segname = O.segname
group by L.order_date, L.segname
;
```

This query generates cumulative sums each date for each segname (segment name).
I have run it through explain with indexes.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how this could be rewritten to work well on MySQL?
(This query works fine in DB2, but I have to use MySQL for this project.)

Thanks for any help!

Tadman requested I add the table definition including indexes.  (Which admittedly, I should have posted initially, so here it is:

```
create table report_PurchasesByOrderDate_Hour_bySegment
(
order_date            date not null,
hour_of_day           int not null,    
hourly_datetime       datetime not null,  
segname               varchar(10),
product_total         decimal(15,4), 
num_orders            bigint,    
PRIMARY KEY (hourly_datetime, segname),
UNIQUE INDEX (order_date, hour_of_day, segname),
UNIQUE INDEX (hour_of_day, order_date, segname)
);
```

Note:  The column hourly_datetime is actually redundant, I put it in while testing left join performance for another query.

Thanks for the feed back.  hour_of_day is indeed used in a different query.
For testing purposes I have added the following indexes.  (Only one of the two would be needed, but I created both for now to see which MySQL would use.)

```
create index test1 on report_PurchasesByOrderDate_Hour_bySegment (order_date, segname);
create index test2 on report_PurchasesByOrderDate_Hour_bySegment (segname, order_date);
```

Here is the explain output from explain used within MySQL Workbench:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,O,ALL,"order_date,test1,test2",NULL,NULL,NULL,253519,"Using temporary; Using filesort"
1,SIMPLE,L,ref,"order_date,test1,test2",test2,12,wc_store.O.segname,1267,"Using where; Using index"
```

I have run this both on my own laptop and an Amazon Managed MySQL database instance.  The explain is identical for both.

On a side note as to why the hour_of_day clause is also in the pre-existing index.
There is another version of the select that aggregates by hour_of_day.  It also performs badly (worse) but I posted the simpler of two, as the solution to the first one above (if there is one) can be applied to the more complex example.  The other version adds "L.hour_of_day" to the select list and to the group by clause and has the following
on clause in the join:

```
on L.order_date >= O.order_date
   and L.hour_of_day = O.hour_of_day
   and L.segname = O.segname
```

**Update**
cbranch: Correct, the goal is to have a running total per date which sums up all prior dates. I changed the query to match the one you gave, which is correct to distinct the order_date and segname. However it did not improve performance. Given that MySQL sometimes has performance issues with sub-queries used in a join, I went ahead and created a temporary table for the result of the sub-query and put indexes on it. So here is the new version:

```
create temporary table tmp_order_segment as
   select distinct order_date, segname from report_PurchasesByOrderDate_Hour_bySegment;
create unique index tmp_1 on tmp_order_segment (order_date, segname);
create unique index tmp_2 on tmp_order_segment (segname, order_date);


select  L.order_date,   
    L.segname, 
    sum(O.product_total) as c_product_total,    
    sum(O.num_orders) as c_num_orders         
from tmp_order_segment as L 
join report_PurchasesByOrderDate_Hour_bySegment as O
    on L.order_date >= O.order_date
        and L.segname = O.segname
group by L.order_date, L.segname;
```

Unfortunately, this did not improve performance either. The query still runs for well over an hour. The explain output is:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,O,ALL,order_date,NULL,NULL,NULL,252264,"Using temporary; Using filesort"
1,SIMPLE,L,ref,"tmp_1,tmp_2",tmp_2,12,bsupply.O.segname,1,"Using where; Using index"
```

MySQL versions I have tried with this issue are: 5.5.24 and 5.5.27.
Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You'll need to post your table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE report_PurchasesByOrderDate_Hour_bySegment`) to get a sense of what indexes are defined.

Comment: I've edited the original question and added the table definition including indexes.Thanks tadman!

Comment: Maybe the MySQL configuration is bad. Switch tables to INNODB if they aren't and then check the configuraion (memory limits and other settings).

Comment: In the revised code above, the `tmp_1` and `tmp_2` indexes are created on your original table, not your temp table.  If fixing the indexes still doesn't resolve the performance issue, then I'm out of ideas for a SQL-only solution.  If it were me, I'd be tempted to write code (C#/PHP/etc.) to do the aggregation.  You should be able to do it in a single pass.  I know that pulling 250K rows certainly isn't ideal, but I bet it will perform much better than what you have now.

Comment: Actually, you could still do the initial date+segment aggregation with SQL, then do the running total in code.  Based on your `EXPLAIN` output with your temp table, it looks like that would reduce the result set so that you'd be processing ~10K rows in code, which is not nearly as bad.

Comment: cbranch:  Good catch on my index mistake.  I corrected the table being indexed (and corrected it in the example question.)  Unfortunately, no change.  It still chooses to use a temp object and filesort the O table.  I updated the explain output to match.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the output from `EXPLAIN`, so this is just a guess ...

You have two composite indexes that look like they MIGHT be usable for this query, except that both indexes include `hour_of_day` which is not part of you search criteria, so may disqualify those indexes.  Try changing your first unique index to one of:

```
UNIQUE INDEX (order_date, segname, hour_of_day)
```

or

```
UNIQUE INDEX (segname, order_date, hour_of_day)
```

NOTE: If the existing index is required for other queries, add a new index rather than replacing the existing one.

**EDIT:**

Is the goal to generate a running total which sums up all prior orders?  If so, I think you need to do the grouping prior to joining.  Otherwise, you're joining table O to every individual row (hourly) in table L rather than one row per date, per segment.  See if this makes sense:

```
select
    L.order_date,   
    L.segname, 
    sum(O.product_total) as c_product_total,    
    sum(O.num_orders) as c_num_orders
from
    (select distinct order_date, segname from report_PurchasesByOrderDate_Hour_bySegment) as L
    join report_PurchasesByOrderDate_Hour_bySegment as O
        on (L.order_date >= O.order_date and L.segname = O.segname)
group by
    L.order_date,
    L.segname
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have edited the question above and added new indexes and the explain output.  It is interesting that MySQL only appears to use the first key in the index for the L table and will not use an index for the O table.  It uses a temporary object with a file sort instead.  I'm not sure how to force it to use an index...  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: cbranch:  Thanks for the suggestion above, it was a great idea.  Unfortunately, it did not resolve the performance issue.  Since the response block here does not permit me to enter enough text to respond with detail, I edited your response above and added a new block below called EDIT Response where I included details.  (I am new to Stack Overflow, so if that was incorrect behavior please let me know.  My feelings are not hurt by valid criticism or correction.  :)  Thank you for your time.  Any other thoughts on this issue?

Comment: @RobD - You should edit your question to clarify things, not the answer. Other people trying to give an answer may miss it here.

Comment: Thanks mata.  I have moved the response I originally placed in cbranch's edit to the bottom of my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a greater than comparison won't use an index, but a between will.
Try this:

```
...
on report_PurchasesByOrderDate_Hour_bySegment as O
    on L.order_date between O.order_date and now()
...
```

this has the same meaning, but will use an index on `order_date` if one exists. If it doesn't exist, create one.

Comment: There is an index on order_date.  Changing the >= to use between was a good idea.  Unfortunately, it had no effect.  The explain output was the same.  (It still chose to use the segname index for the O table and no index for the L table.)

Comment: @RobD which version of MySQL Server? There was a bug in MySQL regarding date fields and index use

Comment: MySQL versions I have tried with this issue are:  5.5.24 and 5.5.27.